# How to get number of rows deleted using deleteAll()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-repositories, mongorepository

I want to get number of deleted rows with `deleteAll()` using SpringRepository. It is pretty simple to obtain this if I write my own function, just like in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796849/spring-repository-get-number-of-deleted-rows). However, I want to override `deleteAll()` method. The following code doesn't work:

```
public interface CalculationInfoRepository extends MongoRepository<CalculationInfo, Long> {
  @Override
  @Modifying
  int deleteAll(Iterable<? extends CalculationInfo> entities);
}
```

because I get

> The return type is incompatible with
> CrudRepository<CalculationInfo,Long>.deleteAll(Iterable<? extends
> CalculationInfo>)

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `CrudRepository#deleteAll` returns void by definition, you cannot override a return type. But you can create your own method, e.g., `int deleteAllAndGetCount`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html

Comment: How would you implement such method? All I can think of is it returning either `size()` of given iterable (which wouldn't help, because we have no idea how many entities were actually removed from the DB) or first query for the number of matching entities (which also wouldn't help, because we don't want to perform any additional query)

Comment: seems possible (eg [in postgres](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/sql-how-to-get-the-number-of-deleted-rows-in-postgresql/)) but an extra query might be simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query` annotation:

```
public interface CalculationInfoRepository extends MongoRepository<CalculationInfo, String> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "{id : {$in: :#{#ids}}}", delete = true)
    int deleteCalculationInfos(@Param("ids") Iterable<String> ids);
}
```

It will delete rows by ids with `String` type and return number of deleted rows.

Comment: That's true, you can even write `@Modifying int deleteByIdIn(Iterable<String> id);` without using `@Query` notation. Spring will handle it. I just wanted to make code as clean as possible and not write additional methods.